AlmaLinux 9.4 how to update MariaDB to a later version
I have a brand new AlmaLinux 9.4 installation with my hosting company and it appears to have been pre-installed with a LAMP stack.
The MariaDB server version currently running is MariaDB 10.5.22 but I notice the release notes for AlmaLinux 9.4 mention an updated module stream to MariaDB 10.11
I am wondering how I can upgrade MariaDB.
Doing dnf update and dnf upgrade tells me there is nothing to do.
Doing dnf search mariadb lists a bunch of MariaDB stuff, but doesn't actually say the version.
Obviously doing dnf install mariadb tells me Package mariadb-3:10.5.22-1.el9_2.alma.1.x86_64 is already installed
So how would I upgrade MariaDB to the later version of MariaDB 10.11, but still stick with a package officially supported and maintained by AlmaLinux?

Firstly, backup your databases and then stop the mariadb daemon.
Next, enable the mariadb 10.11 module.
yum module enable mariadb:10.11

You can use dnf but I use yum out of habit.
Run the mariadb-upgrade binary. You may need to add a username and password or other options. You can see a list of them via the man page for mariadb-upgrade or mariadb-upgrade --help.
Afterwards,
yum update mariadb

Lastly, verify that the configs are what you want (they most likely are unless you want to add something else) and then start the mariadb daemon.
